# What's the best way to limit user to access other information in loopback?

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs, loopback

How do I limit user to access other information?
I have a customer model, by default I can limit access by roles, but all "user" role can access customer model. I don't want other to be able to access other people customer by guessing other id number. Only support role can freely access all the information. How do I do that?

Comment: Have you read any of the documentation on access control? https://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Authentication%2C+authorization%2C+and+permissions ? What have you tried?

Comment: I am not talking about access control, I am talking about user 'A' can only access their personal information and can't access others. By default, as long as you login and you have other people ID, you can freely access the information. I did find out I can user context obj. in the beforeremote method and force assigned the ID to the object, I am not sure if that's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

ACL's are perfect for what you want!

Create your custom user, extended from the base LoopBack user Model:

```
$ slc loopback:model
? Enter the model name: BookUser
? Select the data-source to attach BookUser to: db (memory)
? Select model's base class User
? Expose BookUser via the REST API? Yes
? Custom plural form (used to build REST URL):
? Common model or server only? common
Let's add some BookUser properties now.

Enter an empty property name when done.
? Property name: Name
(!) generator#invoke() is deprecated. Use generator#composeWith() - see http://yeoman.io/authoring/composability.html
   invoke   loopback:property
? Property type: string
? Required? No
```

Deny all requests to /Users, then explicitly grant what you want.

**Deny**

```
$ slc loopback:acl
? Select the model to apply the ACL entry to: BookUser
? Select the ACL scope: All methods and properties
? Select the access type: All (match all types)
? Select the role All users
? Select the permission to apply Explicitly deny access
```

**Allow "owner" (E.G. the user that is logged in) findById**

```
$ slc loopback:acl
? Select the model to apply the ACL entry to: BookUser
? Select the ACL scope: A single method
? Enter the method name findById
? Select the role The user owning the object
? Select the permission to apply Explicitly grant access
```

Now open your API Explorer, and POST to user twice, creating two users.

Then login as the first user (id of 1), setting your access key.

**Try to access /Users/2 (second user).**

```
{
  "error": {
    "name": "Error",
    "status": 401,
    "message": "Authorization Required",
    "statusCode": 401,
    "code": "AUTHORIZATION_REQUIRED",
    "stack": "Error: Authorization Required\n   ..."
  }
}
```

**Now try to access /Users/1 (the currently logged in user).**

```
{
  "email": "someguy@somesite.com",
  "id": 1
}
```

Comment: Here's something interesting however, I found that if I have 2 different sub-types of User with the same ID (rare but may happen, especially locally), you can login as "id: 1" and access the other sub-type with the same ID!!  I'm in the process of searching for an answer to this:  /member/1 and /judge/1 can be accessed with the same login!